# Can't use custom classes as types anymore - something broke

Tags: xcode, header-files

I have a strange problem, this is my Headerfile ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MapField.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UIView *simField;
IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentControl;
IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;
double fieldAlpha;
IBOutlet UISlider *alphaSlider;
double tickTime;
int totalNumberOfCars;
}

/*shortened, here are the property ... declarations usually */

-(MapField*)findDepartureField;
-(MapField*)findDestinationField;
```

The class MapField.h looks like that:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface MapField : UIImageView{
    UIViewController *delegate;
    int x;
    int y;
    int numberOfCars;
    double wAb;
    double wAn;
    int dFahrtdauer;

 }


 @property (nonatomic) int x;
 @property (nonatomic) int y;
 @property (nonatomic) int numberOfCars;
 @property (nonatomic) double wAb;
 @property (nonatomic) double wAn;
 @property (nonatomic) int dFahrtdauer;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *delegate;


 -(void)setDisplayMode:(int)mode;


 @end
```

Looks fine and worked always fine, however I get a strange error in ViewController.h in these two lines:

```
-(MapField*)findDepartureField;
-(MapField*)findDestinationField;
```

Error: Expected a type (and MapField is marked red).

I don't get it. I checked everything a thousand times. It must work! There must be some strange error somewhere else!

Answer (score 0):

Add `@class MapField` just above your `@interface` call on ViewController, to tell the compiler that yes, it is a class.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating `#import ViewController.h` from `MapField` and adding `@class ViewController` ( if necessary) would work. To me, it seems the problem is the cyclic reference of .h files, and Reference to `ViewController.h` seems unnecessary. If needed, you can use `@class` forward declaration for `ViewController` class.